# How to stop a timer after it is done running?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a Console App and in the main method, I have code like this:

```
Timer time = new Timer(seconds * 1000); //to milliseconds
time.Enabled = true;
time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(time_Elapsed);
```

I only want the timer to run once so my idea is that I should stop the timer in the time_Elapsed method. However, since my timer exists in Main(), I can't access it.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer rather or System.Windows.Forms.Timer?
Please specify because I came here for the same question but the answer is for a different timer and is of no help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have access to the Timer inside of the `timer_Elapsed` method:

```
public void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = (Timer)sender; // Get the timer that fired the event
    timer.Stop(); // Stop the timer that fired the event
}
```

The above method will stop whatever Timer fired the Event (in case you have multiple Timers using the same handler and you want each Timer to have the same behavior).

You could also set the behavior when you instantiate the Timer:

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.AutoReset = false; // Don't reset the timer after the first fire
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do and you answered correctly first, so a big check!

Comment: As an aside, having `AutoReset = true` as the default seems a bit mental to me. I've forgotten to set it to `false` quite a number of times and run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

A little example app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int seconds = 2;
        Timer time = new Timer(seconds * 1000); //to milliseconds
        time.Enabled = true;
        time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyHandler);

        time.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MyHandler(object e, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        var timer = (Timer) e;
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're using `System.Timers.Timer` rather than `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

You have two options.

First, as probably the best, is to set the `AutoReset` property to `false`. This should do exactly what you want.

```
time.AutoReset = false;
```

The other option is to call `Stop` in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the System.Threading.Timer. Its constructor takes two time-related parameters:

- The delay before the first "tick" (due time)
- The period

Set the period to Timeout.Infinite to prevent from firing again.

Comment: How do you set it to Timeout.Infinite is probably a reasonable question - it's not obvious