# Use timer to fire function

Tags: c#, timer

My application is **always running** to updating record. I have function to send excel file with email. It will send by the time I set it on a daily basis. So I **use timer method**. It can fire my function. I set timer interval is 100. Let say clock now is 10.00 PM, if same in database then it **will fire sendMail function**.

But the problem now, timer will fire my function **more than once**, I think there are about 10 times or less. I just **want fire once only**. What is the **best way** should I use?

```
// 0 is off and 1 is on
int on_off = int.Parse(class_ta.getValue("tbl_setting", "value", "name", "onOffMail"));

if (on_off == 1)
{
    DataTable dtSendTime = class_ta.valueTimeSend(0);

    foreach (DataRow row in dtSendTime.Rows)
    {
        DateTime dtFire = DateTime.Parse(row["sendTime"].ToString());
        TimeSpan tsHour = TimeSpan.Parse(dtFire.Hour.ToString());
        TimeSpan tsMinutes = TimeSpan.Parse(dtFire.Minute.ToString());

        if (tsHour == TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString()) && tsMinutes == TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes.ToString()) && 0 == int.Parse(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds.ToString()))
        {
            sendMail();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me to resolved this problem, Thanks.

Comment: You can use an Interval of `1000` instead of `100`, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes, as 100 is 1/10th of a second its going to fire 10 times per second.

Comment: your code doesn't show anything related to timers. Please post the relevant code

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722828/how-to-stop-a-timer-after-it-is-done-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the timer as soon as it fires once.

```
timer1.Stop();
```

or

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
```

Do this as the first line in your Tick event.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Enabled` field to `false`, as soon as your event has fired.

```
timer.Enabled = false;
```

You can also stop the timer by calling

```
timer.Stop(); // sets timer.Enabled to false
```

[Source: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

**Edit:**

Another possibility would be to simply increase your timer's interval

```
timer.Interval = 1000;
```

That way you don't need to disable/re-enable the timer all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell anything about your timer from your code, so this is a guess, but you could try including the following as the first line of code inside your timer's `tick` event:

```
myTimer.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your Interval time from 100 to 1000.

Your firing your email function 10 times in one second.

Answer (score 1):

As they always say, don't re-invent the wheel. Instead of having your application always running, why not launch it from Windows Task Scheduler? That way, you can remove all timer and scheduling code from your app and let it focus on sending the email when it is launched.

Alternatively, if you need to control the schedule by what is in the database, I would set some information in the database to signal that the email was sent.

If each row only needs to send one email ever, add a `IsSent` column to your table that defaults to 0. When you query the table, use this in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE IsSent = 0
    AND sendTime <= GetDate()
```

Then you know any rows that are returned will be ones that need an email sent *now*. For each one, send the email, then update the `IsSent` column for that row to 1.

If each row needs to send an email at a certain time every day, add a `LastSentTime` column to your table that defaults to NULL.

```
WHERE (@LastSentTime IS NULL OR DateDiff(day, @LastSentTime, GetDate()) > 0)
    AND @SendTime-DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@SendTime),0) < GetDate()-DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GetDate()),0)
```

For each one, send the email, then update the `LastSentTime` for that row to the current time.